# combine one band rasters to get a multiband raster

Tags: r, raster

I have 4 one-band's rasters (same resolution, same extents...) that I want to combine to have a four-band's raster. Anyone could tell me how to do this with R?
Thank you.

Comment: have you looked at `?raster::stack` ?

Comment: is the with R's matrices, sp's SpatialGridDataFrame, raster's raster, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a raster stack of rasters of same extent and resolution, use the stack function in the raster package:

```
s  <-  stack(raster1,  raster2)
```

In this case the raster can be a raster object or a file path to a raster.

edit (concrete example):

```
library(raster)
fn  <-  system.file("external/test.grd",  package="raster")
s  <-  stack(raster(fn),  raster(fn)*2) #here i had to create the raster object since I 
#was multiplying one of the input rasters 
s

class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 115, 80, 9200, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 40, 40  (x, y)
extent      : 178400, 181600, 329400, 334000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:28992     
+towgs84=565.237,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857,0.350733,-1.87035,4.0812 +proj=sterea 
+lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 
+ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs 
names       :  test.1,  test.2 
min values  : 128.434, 256.868 
max values  : 1805.78, 3611.56
```

Comment: the problem with stack is that I obtain a rasterStack with 4 layers, and what I want to have is a single rasterLayer with 4 bands. Concretely, I have a rasterlayer with only the red band, another with the blue band and a third with the green one. I want to combine them to have an RGB rasterlayer.

Comment: The layers in a stack work as raster bands- like any multiband raster, you can open the tif stack in arcgis and assign bands to the RGB channels to test it out. In R, if you want to display certain bands of an stack as a RGB composite, you can use the plotRGB function in the raster package: plotRGB(stack_raster,  r=1,  g=2,  b=3,  stretch='hist'); where the numbers represent the stack layer indexes.